# OCI 'list_compartments' returning different results when checking the length of the total count

Tags: python

I am trying to get a list of all compartments. In the GUI using Tenancy Explorer I always see 100 compartments. However with the API I noticed I am getting varying results. randomly I get a count of between 98 and 100. The code I'm using below is the most basic.

```
import oci

config = oci.config.from_file()
identity = oci.identity.IdentityClient(config)
print(len(identity.list_compartments(config["tenancy"], compartment_id_in_subtree=True).data))
```